# Why isn't PHPmyadmin picking up my table row data?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I clearly made an account on register.php then when i test the code in the SQL section i get  Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0010 sec) even though there is an account its returning that there is none help? Thanks!

Comment: if PHPMyAdmin doesn't show any data, there probably is no data. You'd need to show the database code in your register.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isnt sql showing the table row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650351/why-isnt-sql-showing-the-table-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test outside of PHPmyadmin and also confirm that your PHPmyadmin has your DB allocated under your login. Then check your register.php..