# Why isn't SQL showing the table row?

Tags: php, sql, row

I clearly made an account on `register.php`. Then, when I test the code in the SQL section, I get rows 0 - 0 shown (one total, query took 0.0010 sec). Even though there is an account it's returning that there is none.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "izzydog";
    $db_name = "challenge1";
    $db_password = "********";
    $tbl_name = "database1"; // Table name]
    $database1 = 'database1';

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "izzydog", "********") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("challenge1",$conn)or die("cannot select DB");

    // Username and password sent from form
    $myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

    // To protect MySQL injection (more details about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $database1 WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if ($count == 1) {
        session_register('myusername');
        session_register('mypassword');
        header('location:login_success.php');
    }
    else {
        echo 'Wrong Username or Password';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the passwords match after all the escaping/filtering?

Answer (score 1):

You should find out if your phpMyAdmin settings are setup correctly and are connecting to the right database, whether you're looking at the right table, etc. You haven't provided a lot of information to articulate towards your issue specifically.

Also, you are using a SELECT statement in the code you have posted, which will return results from the database table. You should be using the INSERT statement in SQL to insert new rows into your database.

If you are looking for some help for a registration or login script, here is a good example to work with that I wrote a while ago: https://gist.github.com/1099006

Comment: This is a login page, not a register one.

Comment: He named the file 'register.php', but either way I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not insert anything which is quite confusing even though you say you have records, so, perhaps as shomz said, check that your criteria matched when escaped but also shouldn't

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $database1 WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword';"
```

be more like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $database1 . "WHERE username='" . $myusername . "' AND password='" . $mypassword . "';"
```

#### My `r.php` file

```
<?php
    /**
     * TODO
     *  - validate post data before proceeding with database connection etc
     *    regex password ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20})
     *    regex email ^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+
     *                (\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
     *  - add salt field
     *  - generate random salt and hash password
     *  - add status field default 0
     *  - add email confirmation which will update status field to 1
     */

    // Get post data
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    // Init connection
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","foo","bar") or die ("CONNECTION FAILURE");

    // Connect to database
    mysql_select_db("test",$conn);

    // The insert statement
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO usr(name,password,email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
                mysql_escape_string($username), mysql_escape_string($password), mysql_escape_string($email));

    // Execute insert statement
    mysql_query($query) or die("INSERT QUERY FAILURE");

    // Test entry remove when OK
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from usr");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['name'] . '<br/>';
    }
    // Test entry end
?>
```

#### My HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test PHP
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="r.php" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>Name: <input type="text" name="username" /></li>
                <li>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></li>
                <li>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using a default recent [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) install. It may be worth the while that you get [Xdebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) which I think has come setup as default with the WAMP version and making sure error checking is strict, etc.

Comment: Are you sure your data is being posted from the form and actually calling the php?